# Google sheets Formula not working when put as conditional formatting formula

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AT2,workpattern)))>0

Trying to search if the cell AT2 contains any of the acceptable answers found in the named range 'workpattern'. Then I want to highlight the cell AT2 red if its not an acceptable answer

Problem is the formula is invalid in the conditional formatting pane

Comment: In conditional formatting rule you can't use `Named Range` directly. Use `INDIRECT()` function to make it workable. Try `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AT2,INDIRECT(workpattern))))>0`.

Comment: That works, but you need to put " " around the named range